# Adding my own static webpage to a wordpress site

Tags: php, html, wordpress, web

If my title wasn't clear, basically what I'm trying to do is to add my own `HTML` or `PHP` page to Wordpress, so i can play around with some web dev.

So essentially I just want a test page/pages added to my site. However since I have installed Wordpress on my website, I can't just add "index.html" to my root folder using my `FTP` client. I wonder if I can/can't do this and if so how to link to the pages I add using `FTP`.

Sorry if this doesn't make any sense. I just want to add some of the sites I've already made / ones I am creating to my site so I can easily show clients/employers what I can do, and I apologize again if I'm being an idiot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a sub-directory in your root folder and then simply link to it:

`www.domain.com/mysubdir/index.php`

Comment: See I tried that, but I just keep getting a " Page Cannot be Displayed". If you know any reason why it would do that?

Comment: 404, sorry I forgot to put that in the reply.

Comment: Hmm, it's hard to describe really, But my site has literally nothing on it but WordPress, unless it's something to do with protection or something...

Comment: www.rhysdrury.com then click new page, ignore the content it's for my blog for my university module.

Comment: The `public_html` part of your link is superfluous. Your link should simply be `http://www.rhysdrury.com/Testpage/Testpage.php`

Comment: Oh my god I am an idiot. Thanks a lot mate. I was following this guide on another forum and they said put the public_html in!

Answer (score 4):

the other way to do this... create a page template in wordpress

1. create a php file named: template_mypage.php
2. You must put this php comment line at the top of your template file:

   /* Template Name: My Page */
3. go to wordpress backend and create a new page
4. in the "Page Attributes", you can find a drop down list named "Template". In the list, you should be able to find "My Page"... select it and then save your page.
5. view it!

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a subdomain or create a folder inside public_html/www/ and redirect it from any other domain or from any static link you have on wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Why not use WordPress and put your portfolio together using Custom Post Types? I recently presented on this and there is a handy plugin for Custom Post Types UI that you can create a whole new section of your site and make templates for your portfolio.

Just a thought.

If you do a static page in WordPress, you can still template using the Page system as specified in another comment. Code your page, separate it into header, footer, content, etc files. You can load the file to your root, but not name it index. If you do a subfolder, you need to not have an existing page in WordPress.

HOWEVER, you can still do a "halfway" static page still using WordPress and do a header-staticpage.php, index-staticpage.php, and footer-staticpage.php and make sure to include the code for WordPress header and footer in the new header and footer so you can still reap the benefits of the default jquery that WordPress allows. Don't forget to name your template and when you create the page in WordPress, you can just leave the content area blank if you have hardcoded the page's content in.

I still recommend trying Custom Post Types. It is not hard and there are some great presentations in Slideshare that cover this aside from the plugin I mentioned earlier in this comment.